# WXcode Update in App Store not starting? How to update Xcode correctly?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, software-update

I amm trying to update Xcode on my MacBook Air (newest OS).

Whenever I try to start the update it doesn't look like its getting downloaded.

The process is not going on and sticking at the beginning, see screenshot:

[image]

What should I do? I already restarted my MacBook several times with no luck.

Maybe I have to download the Xcode at the Apple Developers page directly?

But I need to uninstall Xcode first? How does the installation work with the manually downloaded Xcode zip file?

Or should I just wait till the download process is going on at the App Store?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is fairly large - probably the download is in progress but will take quiet a long time?

You can also try to update Xcode from the command line by running

```
softwareupdate --install -a
```

This should perform all pending updates, including Xcode, provided MacOS is already updated to the latest version.

Comment: Yea sure, but I mean my internet also quite fast.. No matter, its still at the same progress like on the screenshot. Its just not moving on..

Comment: How long have you waited?

Do other updates in App Store work? Have you checked the internet connection? If so, maybe your IP is banned by App Store, or there is some other explanation that App Store isn't able to connect.

Comment: I waited more than 90 minutes for now. Other updates are working fine. I did an update right now for testing purposes..

Comment: Sorry but Softwareupdate is not working, because Xcode is downloaded from the App Store. The are no software updates available..

Comment: OK, please provide the exakt error message you get. Edit your original question to inlcude it. Also, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and make sure to follow the recommendations there when editing your question. Thanks!